# Set the default font narrower

Tags: fonts

I was trying to find the answer for my problem, but I didn't found anything good.
The default font in Latex is `Computer_Modern`. But in my document, the letters are very wide. Is any possibility to set this default font narrower?
I tried to use another fonts, but then everything in document is changing (for example, the section and subsection topics aren't bold, what is not good for me).

```
\documentclass[11pt,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[MeX]{polski}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[pdftex]{color,graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\geometry{verbose,a4paper,tmargin=2.8cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=2.6cm,rmargin=2.6cm}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\begin{document}
 This is an example. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you show a minimal example of what you have?

Comment: @egreg But you want to see the fragment of pdf file or a pice of code where I set the font?

Comment: The code, please.

Comment: @egreg I edited my post

Comment: A very widely used narrow font is Times and its variants. Of all its LaTeX variants maybe `\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}` is the best currently.

Comment: ... Not that I would deliberately use Times for anything.

Comment: @marczellm No, I don't want to change the font, especially for Times

Comment: @Ziva TeX has no standard way to deform the letters so changing the font is basically your only option. (If you have an issue with bold sections then you need to show that code)

Comment: @Ziva And it is not a good idea (typographically) to alter fonts in that way. Much better to use a font whose creator designed it with narrower glyphs than to deform one designed with wider characters. It need not be Times - marczellm was just giving that as an example. Obviously if you want bold section headings, just make sure you pick a font which has bold. Most do. Which alternatives have you tried?

Comment: Some OpenType fonts (requires the use of XeTeX or LuaTeX engine; i.e., using `xelatex` or `lualatex` as your compile command) have an OpenType feature called 'CharacterWidth' (see the `fontspec` manual for details; or [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typographic_features)).  Apparently this is especially true of Asian fonts, but I've never tried to find a font that has such a characteristic....

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to give some examples of narrower fonts with bold faces for which packages are provided on CTAN and in TeX Live:

[image: Examples of fonts narrower than CMR with bold weights and standard support packages]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand*{\test}{This is an example. and \textbf{This is some bold.}\par}

\begin{document}
 CMR:\par
 \test
 \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{yvt}\rmfamily
 Venturis:\par
 \test
 \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{yv2}\rmfamily
 Venturis2:\par
 \test
 \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{yvo}\rmfamily
 Venturis Old:\par
 \test
 \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ybv}\rmfamily
 Baskervald:\par
 \test
 \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ybd}\rmfamily
 Berenis:\par
 \test
 \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{gentium}\rmfamily
 Gentium:\par
 \test
\end{document}
```

Don't use those commands if you want to use these fonts, obviously, load the relevant packages instead e.g. `\usepackage{venturis2}` or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out this package?

http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/paratypesansnarrow/

Usage (from the website):

```
\usepackage{PTSansNarrow} 
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} %% Only if the base font of the     document is to be sans serif
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

It allows you to define a new default font which is significantly narrower. In did not experience any changes in the layout of the document as you mention.