# Set the default font more narrow. Cyrillic case

Tags: fonts, cyrillic

I make a document in Russian using the following construction to include Russian fonts:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
```

I need that the font of the whole document would be more narrow than it is by default. Is it possible to achieve this, and how?

The best that I found on this topic is this, [Set the default font narrower](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154296/set-the-default-font-narrower), but the answer by cfr doesn't work with T2* encodings. It just removes bold style and prints the corresponding text as ordinary.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You might do `\usepackage{tempora}` that selects a font based on Times, which is narrower than the default font.

Comment: Do you want the spaces between letters to be narrower, or the letters themselves to be narrower?

Comment: @MichaelFraiman I would like that the letters themselves to be narrower.

Comment: @egreg I have tried to install tempora from CTAN (it is absent in TeXLive my distribution; I run it at openSUSE 42.2). I downloaded tempora.tds.zip, and copied its content into /usr/local/share/texmf/ (the result of `> kpsewhere -var-value TEXMFLOCAL`). Then I made `> texhash`. However now pdflatex returns the following error:

`!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file Tempora-Regular-tlf-t1--base): Font Tempora-Regul
ar-tlf-t1--base at 600 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!`

Comment: You have also to enable the map file: `sudo updmap-sys --enable tempora.map`

Comment: `# updmap-sys --enable tempora.map
Try "updmap --help" for more information.
Try "updmap --help" for more information.`

Looked at help and tried
`# updmap --enable Map=tempora.map`

After long list of map-files it to do this with --syncwithtrees. I had done this... But that error is present.

Comment: @natasha then you have to find a font that you find narrow enough and use it via 'fontspec' package.

Comment: @egreg Thank you. Tempora has helped. It uses some more narrow font, other than the default. I cannot say how I have achieved this, but tempora became working (I also tried to install fonts through `getnonfreefonts`, maybe it had done something implicitly...).

Comment: @MichaelFraiman I have tried to use 'fontspec', but it requires XeTeX or LuaTeX. At my system they don't process Cyrillic letters. Seems, this problem may be solved, but I didn't dig this, since 'tempora' has helped. Thank you too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A narrower text font is provided by the `tempora` package; its Tempora font is based on Times New Roman and supports the Latin, Greek and Cyrillic alphabets. Add

```
\usepackage{tempora}
```

to your preamble after `\usepackage[russian]{babel}`.

You may need to update your TeX system in order to have it available.

### Example (text from Wikipedia about Moscow).

You can see that the last paragraph saves one line.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\usepackage{tempora}

\begin{document}

Москва (произношение (инф.)) — столица Российской Федерации, город 
федерального значения, административный центр Центрального федерального 
округа и центр Московской области, в состав которой не входит. 
Крупнейший по численности населения город России и её 
субъект — 12 380 664[2] чел. (2017), самый населённый из городов, 
полностью расположенных в Европе, входит в первую десятку городов 
мира по численности населения[5]. Центр Московской городской агломерации.

Историческая столица Великого княжества Московского, Русского царства, 
Российской империи (в 1728—1730 годах), Советской России и СССР. Город-герой. 
В Москве находятся федеральные органы государственной власти Российской 
Федерации (за исключением Конституционного суда), посольства иностранных 
государств, штаб-квартиры большинства крупнейших российских коммерческих 
организаций и общественных объединений.

Расположена на реке Москве в центре Восточно-Европейской равнины, 
в междуречье Оки и Волги. Как субъект федерации Москва граничит 
с Московской и Калужской областями.

Москва — важный туристический центр России. Московский Кремль, 
Красная площадь, Новодевичий монастырь и Церковь Вознесения в Коломенском 
входят в список Всемирного наследия ЮНЕСКО[6]. Она является важнейшим 
транспортным узлом. Город обслуживают 5 аэропортов, 9 железнодорожных вокзалов, 
3 речных порта (имеется речное сообщение с морями бассейнов Атлантического и 
Северного Ледовитого океанов). С 1935 года в Москве работает метрополитен.

\end{document}
```

### Output *without* `\usepackage{tempora}`

[image]

### Output *with* `\usepackage{tempora}`

[image]