# Fonts like Times New Roman for Russian Language

Tags: fonts, cyrillic, times

Where can I download free (open-source) fonts like Times New Roman for Russian Language?

1. The collection of fonts `PSCyr` is given [here](ftp://scon155.phys.msu.su/pub/russian/psfonts/) or [here](http://tex.imm.uran.ru/texserver/fonts/pscyr/pscyr4c/pscyr4c.html#l1).

It is said: "`Times` within `PSCyr` has been developed by Monotype and exported from Windows". Is it open-source? The licence published seems to prove this.

2. Information about `tempora` is given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/377736/44348) and [on CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tempora).
3. [In this book](http://www.tex.uniyar.ac.ru/doc/kotelnikovchebotaev2004b.pdf) by @Igor-Kotelnikov `TimesC` package has mentioned, however I can not find it on CTAN.
4. RobtAll commented: "Liberation Serif (from LuaLaTeX and XeTeX) is compatible with TNR"

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375461/set-the-default-font-more-narrow-cyrillic-case help? The `tempora` font is included in TeX Live and MiKTeX

Comment: @egreg, thank you so much. I'm trying to collect all types of fonts, including `TimesC`. The question is updated.

Comment: Since Igor Kotelnikov seems to be a member of this community, maybe he can answer. I added the [tag:cyrillic] tag to this purpose, hoping he's following it.

Comment: If you use LuaLaTeX or XeTeX, you can access a wide range of characters via their utf-8 codes. Some free Open Type or TrueType fonts that include Cyrillic are the Liberation and Libertinus fonts. Of these, Liberation Serif is compatible with TNR. I very firmly suggest that anyone who needs multilingual support switch away from the old, last-century Type 1 technology of pdftex.

Comment: I don't support FontsC package any more since I moved to XeTeX. I could send FontsC by email as is but I forgot how to install it. Unfortunetely I've lost distributable form of FontsC bundle but I'll try to ask my collegues who might have it.

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov, thank you for the letter and the `package`